# terraform only use properties if value is greater than one?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a variable `var.delete_retention_policy_days`. If the variable is set to `0` then I do not want the policy days block to be enabled. Is there a neat way to do this in terraform?

```
delete_retention_policy {
  days = var.delete_retention_policy_days
}
```

Here is an example of the full resource

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example2" {
  name                     = var.azurerm_storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.parameters.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.parameters.location
  account_tier             = var.azurerm_storage_account_account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.azurerm_storage_account_account_replication_type
  allow_blob_public_access = var.azurerm_storage_account_allow_blob_public_access
  blob_properties {
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = var.delete_retention_policy_days
    }
    versioning_enabled = true
    change_feed_enabled = true
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The capability for conditionally configuring blocks inside of resources is still an outstanding feature request. For the Github issue requesting this feature, the following algorithm was offered by the internal development team as a current workaround:

```
dynamic "<block name>" {
  for_each = range(<conditional> ? 1 : 0)

  content {
    ...
  }
}
```

For your specific situation where `delete_retention_policy_days` is already a  `number` type, this becomes slightly more straightforward:

```
dynamic "delete_retention_policy" {
  for_each = range(length(var.delete_retention_policy_days) > 0 ? 1 : 0)

  content {
    days = var.delete_retention_policy_days
  }
}
```

Note there are also a couple more interesting functions for this conditional capability utilizing the `for_each` meta-argument:

```
# useful for objects with optional keys to iterate on them only if they exist
for_each = try(var.value, [])
# useful for objects with optional keys to conditionally configure a block only if they exist
for_each = range(can(var.value) ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example and info! Will you be able to show an example with my code above? I tried added the dynamic part of your code and removed the days = var.delete_retention_policy_days but I errored out :(

Comment: @user3622142 As specified, the second block of code in my answer is the example for your code that you could copy and paste if you want. Please clarify what is different in your code from your question and/or my answer above to explain why you have an error.