# Terraform conditionally enable/disable azurerm_cdn_endpoint rules and rule-actions?

Tags: terraform

How can I conditionally enable/disable azurerm_cdn_endpoint rules and rule-actions?

Take the following simple example, I want to provide different configurations based on the `var.env` variable.

```js
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "cdn_endpoint" {
  ...
  
  // if var.env === "dev" ... then this... 
  global_delivery_rule {
    cache_expiration_action {
      behavior = "BypassCache"
    }
  }

  // if var.env === "prod" ... then disable this completely
  global_delivery_rule {
    //disable this rule
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about conditional blocks in resources, in which case this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'll try to make it work then post an answer!