# Create optional stage in CodePipeline in Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I have created a TF module to deploy a CodePipeline.

It looks like this

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "test_pipeline" {
  name     = "${var.name}-codepipeline"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.codepipeline_service_role.arn

  artifact_store {
    location = var.artifact_bucket_name
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
    ...
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Non-Prod Deploy"
    count = "${var.non_prod_environment == true ? 1 : 0}"

    action {
      ...
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Prod Deploy"

    action {
      ...
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to create an optional stage inside my pipeline. I tried using count but I get:

```
│ An argument named "count" is not expected here.
```

Probably because it's not a separate resource. How can I achieve to make a stage (part of a resource) optional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [terraform only use properties if value is greater than one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one)

Comment: The above demonstrates optional blocks in Terraform for your purposes.

Comment: The link from @MattSchuchard will solve your problem unless you are using an old version or terraform, if you are using an old version upgrade first ... Read more about Terraform Dynamic Blocks: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

Comment: The answer seems a bit similar indeed but it's replacing some setting like "setting = ...". I'm not sure how it replaces something like stage {}

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution that we come up with:

```
  dynamic stage {
    for_each = range(var.enable_specific_stage ? 1 : 0)
    content {
      name = "InvokeLambda" # Stage name
      action {
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference.html
        name = <action name>
        provider = "Lambda" # Choose to your need
        category = "Invoke" # Choose to your need 
        owner = "AWS"
        version = "1"
        configuration = { })
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here we use `dynamic` block creation along with a terraform Boolean variable `enable_specific_stage`, which will control the no of loops 1/0 accordingly.