# Terraform Condition on Deployment

Tags: terraform

I'm using terraform in deployment.
I have a list of deployment and using for_each on deployment. Based on string condition I need to add a sidecar.

Briefly, I need to write a condition to add a sidecar image.

Something like it:

```
${substr(each.key, 0, 3) == "tst" ? 1 : 0 }
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Here is my deployment tf:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "x" {
  for_each = data
  metadata {
    name = each.key
    labels = {
      app = each.key
      name = each.key
    }
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = each.key
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = each.key
          name = each.key
        }
      }
      spec {
        service_account_name = "default"

        container {
          image = each.value
          image_pull_policy = "Always"
          name = each.key
        }
        // I need a condtion to create the second container
        container {
          image = "sidecar_image"
          image_pull_policy = "Always"
          name = "sidecar-container"
          port {
            name           = "default-port"
            container_port = 50050
          }
        }

        restart_policy = "Always"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can see the nuances around conditional nested blocks [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one/69035305#69035305). To tailor this to your specific situation though:

```
dynamic "container" {
  for_each = range(substr(each.key, 0, 3) == "tst" ? 1 : 0)
 
  content {
    image = "sidecar_image"
    image_pull_policy = "Always"
    name = "sidecar-container"
    port {
      name           = "default-port"
      container_port = 50050
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes well-formed `data` keys in your `for_each` meta-argument value for the resource as provided in your question.

One immediate issue I note with your conditional is that the substring from index 0 to 3 will contain four values, and you are testing against a string with three characters. You probably wanted to do:

```
substr(each.key, 0, 2)
```

or perhaps also:

```
can(regex("^tst", each.key))
```

but either way your provided conditional will always return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `dynamic` block for the second `container` block in order to make it conditional. For example, consider the following piece of code:

```
dynamic "container" {
    for_each          = var.is_test ? [1] : []
    image             = "sidecar_image"
    image_pull_policy = "Always"
    name              = "sidecar-container"
    port {
        name           = "default-port"
        container_port = 50050
    }
}
```

Note that the condition will require some more attention but I think this should be enough to get you started.