# Data module terraform - How to use conditioanl block

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have a data module where I am creating "aws_iam_policy_document" "trust-policy and would like to add conditions only for certain modules, not all.

For example:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "trust-policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [var.action]

    principals {
      type        = var.type
      identifiers = concat(var.trusted_arns)
    }
    count        = var.git ? 1 : 0
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "abc"
      values   = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringLike"
      variable = "dcf"
      values   = ["repo:var.org_name/var.repo_name:ref:refs/heads/var.branch_name"]
    }

  }
}
```

I want to run the condition blocks only if module is git. But with count , it fails with below error:

```
 An argument named "count" is not expected here.
```

Comment: Which `condition` block? Also note conditional blocks in data are basically the same as in `resource`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one/69035305#69035305.

Comment: You can't put `count` inside a `statement` block like that. What specifically are you trying to do here? You probably need to use dynamic blocks: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dynamic` block. For example, declare a new variable `trust_policy_conditions` like this:

```
variable "trust_policy_conditions" {
  description = "A list of trust policy conditions"
  type = list(object({
    test     = string
    variable = string
    values   = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Then add the dynamic block to the data source:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "trust-policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [var.action]

    principals {
      type        = var.type
      identifiers = concat(var.trusted_arns)
    }

    dynamic "condition" {
      for_each = var.git == true ? { for index, policy in var.trust_policy_conditions : index => policy } : {}
      content {
        test     = condition.value.test
        variable = condition.value.variable
        values   = condition.value.values
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the index is the key as there may be a scenario where multiple conditions share the same test or variable attribute.

Comment: I declared this variable and added dynamc condition block but it is not creating the conditions in IAM role even though my var.git == true

Comment: Did you set the variable `trust_policy_conditions`?  In the example I set the default as an empty list

Comment: It was an issue with git string value, it worked. Thanks!