# What does a ternary inside a for_each loop in a dynamic-block do?

Tags: terraform, hcl

In the following example `enable_aggregate_limit` is of `type: bool`. From what I understand it will render the `parameter` argument with `content` if its value is `TRUE` and it does not create the parameter if its `FALSE`.
What does the `["yes"]` and `[]` mean though in the ternary expression and what can I do to create the parameter when the value o `enable_aggregate_limit` is `FALSE`.

```
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "main" {
  name   = local.name
  family = var.custom_parameter_group_family

  dynamic parameter {
    for_each = var.enable_aggregate_limit ? ["yes"] : []
    content {
      name         = "pga_aggregate_limit"
      value        = "0"
      apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a variant on the algorithm for a conditional block. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one/69035305#69035305. Other than that, ternaries behave the same in HCL2 as in any other language, so the first value is returned on a truthy conditional, and the second value on a falsey conditional, and either would be assigned as the value to the `for_each` meta-argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually dynamic blocks are used to create several blocks of code with changing values inside. But in your case it is used together with ternary operator.

If `for_each` has empty value `[]` - dynamic block doesn't create any code.

If `for_each` receive a list as value, it iterates over this list and create several blocks. But in your situation there is only one element `["yes"]`, so it should iterate over `yes` item and create:

```
parameter {
  name         = "pga_aggregate_limit"
  value        = "0"
  apply_method = "pending-reboot"
}
```

To create a parameter when your bool value is FALSE, you should change the condition:

```
for_each = var.enable_aggregate_limit == false ? ["yes"] : []
```

or

```
for_each = var.enable_aggregate_limit ? [] : ["yes"]
```

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated. So that means instead of ["yes"] there could be any string value in the list?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There could be any string for this simple case. But in more complex tasks there could be an `object` containing values, and during the iteration you set these values to your `parameter` values