# How to make optional block inside Terraform resource?

Tags: terraform, newrelic

## Given

I have this code in terraform module (file `newrelic_nrql.tf`):

```
resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "additional_alerts_condition" {
  count = length(var.additional_alerts)

  account_id = var.newrelic_account_id
  policy_id  = newrelic_alert_policy.policy.id

  name        = format("%s-%s", local.container_name, var.additional_alerts[count.index].name_suffix)
  type        = "static"
  runbook_url = var.runbook_url
  enabled     = var.additional_alerts[count.index].enabled

  warning {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurences
  }

  critical {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].critical_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurrences
  }

  nrql {
    query = var.additional_alerts[count.index].query
  }

  aggregation_window = 60
  aggregation_method = "event_flow"
  aggregation_delay  = 120

  slide_by                     = 30
  violation_time_limit_seconds = 3600
}
```

It receives configuration from module input variable `var.additional_alerts`, that is a list of objects:

```
variable "additional_alerts" {
  description = "List of a custom alerts in case you need to create your own one"
  type = list(object({
    name_suffix        = string
    enabled            = bool
    operator           = string
    warning_enabled    = bool
    warning_threshold  = number
    critical_threshold = number
    duration           = number
    occurrences        = string
    query              = string
  }))
  default = []
}
```

## Goal

Please pay attention to object variable `warning_enabled = bool`

My goal is to enable or disable (remove) `warning` block from resource `"additional_alerts_condition"` conditionally, depending on variable `warning_enabled` value.

For example. If `warning_enabled = true`, terraform resource should have both warning and critical blocks:

```
 warning {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurences
  }

  critical {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].critical_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurrences
  }
```

And if `warning_enabled = false`, terraform resource should have critical block only:

```
  critical {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].critical_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurrences
  }
```

## What I've tried

I created 2 similar resources - 1st containing both critical and warning, 2nd - containing critical only. And tried to play with `count` expression, so only one of specified resources will be created.

Warning + Critical:

```
resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "additional_alerts_condition_full" {
  count = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_enabled == true ? length(var.additional_alerts) : 0

  account_id = var.newrelic_account_id
  policy_id  = newrelic_alert_policy.policy.id

  name        = format("%s-%s", local.container_name, var.additional_alerts[count.index].name_suffix)
  type        = "static"
  runbook_url = var.runbook_url
  enabled     = var.additional_alerts[count.index].enabled

  warning {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurences
  }

  critical {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].critical_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurrences
  }
// omitted code
}
```

Critical only:

```
resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "additional_alerts_condition" {
  count = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_enabled == true ? 0 : length(var.additional_alerts)

  account_id = var.newrelic_account_id
  policy_id  = newrelic_alert_policy.policy.id

  name        = format("%s-%s", local.container_name, var.additional_alerts[count.index].name_suffix)
  type        = "static"
  runbook_url = var.runbook_url
  enabled     = var.additional_alerts[count.index].enabled

  critical {
    operator              = var.additional_alerts[count.index].operator
    threshold             = var.additional_alerts[count.index].critical_threshold
    threshold_duration    = var.additional_alerts[count.index].duration
    threshold_occurrences = var.additional_alerts[count.index].occurrences
  }
// omitted code
}
```

In this case I'm getting error:

```
Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context
 
on .terraform/modules/new_relic/newrelic_nrql.tf line 175, in resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "additional_alerts_condition_full":
175:   count = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_enabled == true ? length(var.additional_alerts) : 0

on .terraform/modules/new_relic/newrelic_nrql.tf line 213, in resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "additional_alerts_condition":
213:   count = var.additional_alerts[count.index].warning_enabled == true ? 0 : length(var.additional_alerts)
```

Could anyone please suggest how to fix my code?

Or how this goal can be achieved with other design/approach?

Comment: You can implement conditional blocks with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one/69035305#69035305.

Answer (score 0):

```
    variables.tf
    
    variable "nrql_alert_conditions" {
      type = map(object({
        aggregation_delay              = string
        aggregation_method             = string
        aggregation_window             = number
        close_violations_on_expiration = bool
        enabled                        = bool
        fill_option                    = string
        fill_value                     = number
        expiration_duration            = number
        open_violation_on_expiration   = bool
        slide_by                       = string
        policy_id                      = number
        type                           = string
        violation_time_limit_seconds   = number
        runbook_url                    = string
        nrql_file                      = string
        critical = object({
          operator              = string
          threshold             = number
          threshold_duration    = number
          threshold_occurrences = string
        })
        warning = optional(object({
          operator              = string
          threshold             = number
          threshold_duration    = number
          threshold_occurrences = string
        }))
      }))
    }
    
    main.tf
    
    data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
    
    resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "this" {
      for_each                       = var.nrql_alert_conditions
      name                           = each.key
      policy_id                      = each.value["policy_id"]
      aggregation_delay              = each.value["aggregation_delay"]
      aggregation_method             = each.value["aggregation_method"]
      aggregation_window             = each.value["aggregation_window"]
      close_violations_on_expiration = each.value["close_violations_on_expiration"]
      enabled                        = each.value["enabled"]
      fill_value                     = each.value["fill_value"]
      expiration_duration            = each.value["expiration_duration"]
      fill_option                    = each.value["fill_option"]
      open_violation_on_expiration   = each.value["open_violation_on_expiration"]
      slide_by                       = each.value["slide_by"]
      type                           = each.value["type"]
      violation_time_limit_seconds   = each.value["violation_time_limit_seconds"]
      runbook_url                    = each.value["runbook_url"]
    
      dynamic "critical" {
        for_each = each.value.critical[*]
        content {
          operator              = critical.value.operator
          threshold             = critical.value.threshold
          threshold_duration    = critical.value.threshold_duration
          threshold_occurrences = critical.value.threshold_occurrences
        }
      }
    
      dynamic "warning" {
        for_each = each.value.warning[*]
        content {
          operator              = warning.value.operator
          threshold             = warning.value.threshold
          threshold_duration    = warning.value.threshold_duration
          threshold_occurrences = warning.value.threshold_occurrences
        }
      }
    
      nrql {
        query = file(each.value["nrql_file"])
      }
    }
    
    versions.tf
    
    terraform {
      required_version = ">= 1.2.6"
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        }
        newrelic = {
          source = "newrelic/newrelic"
        }
      }
      experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
    }
    
Here you can have this experiment block if you want the optional warning block, otherwise, you can assign the input as null when you provide the input, either way, it should be fine. And you can use the splat concept to leave the dynamic block as optional
    
    input variable:
    locals {
      nrql_alert_conditions = {
        "Error alert1" = {
          aggregation_delay              = "120"
          aggregation_method             = ""
          aggregation_window             = 600
          close_violations_on_expiration = false
          enabled                        = true
          expiration_duration            = 0
          fill_option                    = "static"
          fill_value                     = 0
          open_violation_on_expiration   = false
          policy_id                      = policyid
          slide_by                       = 60
          type                           = "static"
          violation_time_limit_seconds   = 1800
          runbook_url                    = "https://xxxx"
          nrql_file                      = "samplequery1.nrql"
          critical = {
            operator              = ""
            threshold             = 111
            threshold_duration    = 11
            threshold_occurrences = ""
          }
        }
"Error alert2" = {
          aggregation_delay              = "120"
          aggregation_method             = ""
          aggregation_window             = 600
          close_violations_on_expiration = false
          enabled                        = true
          expiration_duration            = 0
          fill_option                    = "static"
          fill_value                     = 0
          open_violation_on_expiration   = false
          policy_id                      = policyid
          slide_by                       = 60
          type                           = "static"
          violation_time_limit_seconds   = 1800
          runbook_url                    = "https://xxxx"
          nrql_file                      = "samplequery1.nrql"
          critical = {
            operator              = ""
            threshold             = 111
            threshold_duration    = 11
            threshold_occurrences = ""
          }
          warning = {
            operator              = ""
            threshold             = 111
            threshold_duration    = 11
            threshold_occurrences = ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
```