# Using Terraform, how to conditionally include a VPC in a Route53 definition

Tags: dns, terraform, conditional-statements, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

Using Terraform, I need to associate a second VPC, in my AWS Private Route53 Host Zone definition; but only in my *development* account.  I do not want this second VPC association in test or production accounts.  Logically, this is what I would like to do.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "private_dom" {
  name    = "private.dom."
  comment = "Hosted zone for private.dom"

  vpc {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.application.id
  }

  vpc {
    count  = var.account_name == "development" ? 1 : 0
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.management.id
  }
}
```

But, Terraform complains that  `An argument named "count" is not expected here.` Any recommendations for how I can make this work?

Comment: Conditional blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034600/terraform-only-use-properties-if-value-is-greater-than-one/69035305#69035305

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic blocks for it. In your case, it would look like this.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "private_dom" {
  name    = "private.dom."
  comment = "Hosted zone for private.dom"

  vpc {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.application.id
  }

  dynamic "vpc" {
    for_each = var.account_name == "development" ? [1] : []
    content {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.management.id
    }  
  }
}
```